# Magento - Sort products by "Attribute Set"

Tags: magento

In Magento's category list page, it is possible to sort products by Attribute Set?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand this question at all.

Comment: I have edited my question, is it better now ?

Comment: Yes, I do understand that I don't know the solution now ;)

Comment: Yes, just mark your attribute as "Used for sorting in product listing".

Comment: @Gordon, where can I mark that ?

Comment: @Bizboss, I might understood you wrong. I thought you want to sort products by attribute, not attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it be in the front-end or for the Admin section, your requirement of sorting products based on Attribute Set List will go for custom development, as Magento does not provide this sort of thing by default.

You need to understand that the Attribute Set concept was provided for only the creation of Catalog Products, so that the Administrator can segregate / group the attribute(s), as needed for its store.
So if you understand the basic logic here, then you will find that for grouping each products, the concept of category is useful & not the Attribute Set List.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know that Magento does not provide this sort of thing by default, I need a little help to customise the manner of selecting products in the category page, so that I get all products of a same category together, one after the other ans in the same category...